# How can we make sub queries with count where parameters are same for all queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 queries which are useful to  get count from 3 different tables. But I need one single query to get three counts by using sub queries and I am passing
same parameter(user_id) to 3 queries

1st:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_outlet` JOIN `outlet` 
ON `outlet`.`id`=`user_outlet`.`outlet_id`
WHERE `user_outlet`.`user_id`=? AND `user_outlet`.`isActive`=TRUE
```

2nd:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `audit_schedule` JOIN `user_outlet`  
ON `user_outlet`.id=`audit_schedule`.`auditer_id`
WHERE  `audit_schedule`.`auditer_id`=? 
AND MONTH(`audit_schedule`.`schedule_date`)=MONTH(NOW())
```

3rd:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `audit` JOIN `user_outlet` 
ON `user_outlet`.id=`audit`.`auditor_id` 
WHERE  `audit`.`auditor_id`=? AND MONTH(`audit`.`created_date`)=MONTH(NOW())
```

above are 3 queries which I wanted  to make as single query using sub query
and I expected Out put as 
total count for 1st query and planned count for 2nd Query completed count for 3rd query and passing only single parameter user_id (i.e =?)

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Have you tried using UNION ALL?

Comment: Since I am new to sub queries, I have not tried anything yet. I just need some clarity on this sub query. So, I can give try furtherly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse a parameter, you can place it in a derived table (subquery in FROM clause). Example:

```
FROM (SELECT ? as user_id) x
```

Then you can reuse the alias `x.user_id`:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_outlet` JOIN `outlet` 
    ON `outlet`.`id`=`user_outlet`.`outlet_id`
    WHERE `user_outlet`.`user_id`=x.user_id AND `user_outlet`.`isActive`=TRUE
) as total_count, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `audit_schedule` JOIN `user_outlet`  
    ON `user_outlet`.id=`audit_schedule`.`auditer_id`
    WHERE  `audit_schedule`.`auditer_id`=x.user_id 
    AND MONTH(`audit_schedule`.`schedule_date`)=MONTH(NOW())
) as planned_count,
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `audit` JOIN `user_outlet` 
    ON `user_outlet`.id=`audit`.`auditor_id` 
    WHERE  `audit`.`auditor_id`=x.user_id AND MONTH(`audit`.`created_date`)=MONTH(NOW())
) as completed_count
FROM (SELECT ? as user_id) x
```

Comment: Its returning some error near line 11, I just removed placeholder(?) and passed an user_id as 1

Comment: I thought you want to use it in a prepared statement, since you use placeholders in your queries too.

Comment: yes something like that, I used rowmapper and jdbcTemplate